# Checking when a SQL Server SSL Server Authentication Certificate Expires

Tags: sql-server, ssl, certificate

We have just implemented and forced SSL on a few SQL Servers and would like to automated the reporting on the expiration of the certificates.

I had a look at using the below PowerShell script available online, however it has issues with navigating the path and throws an error before traversing all the certificates. This is apparently a known issue?

```
invoke-command -ComputerName <servername> -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -path 'cert:\' -Recurse  | where { $_.notafter -le (get-date).AddDays(60) -AND $_.notafter -gt (get-date)} | select thumbprint, subject
}
```

Throws the below error

```
NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], Win32Exception
```

So I had a look to see if the SSL Server Authentication certificate was recorded in SQL Server and queried `master.sys.certificates` however it was not here.

How do I go about checking for an expiring SSL certificate on Windows Server 2012 R2 for SQL Server 2012+?

Answer (score 0):

I found that limiting the certificate path to for example `cert:\LocalMachine\` resolved the Powershell error and traversed all the certificates in that path